# Add custom html code snippet to my website

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm a Wordpress newbie. I want to add a widget from another site onto my Wordpress website.

Here is the snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://www.freshcontent.net/canada_news_feed.php"></script>
```

It will create something like a ticker on my site. I know how to add custom html to my posts. But, how do I make this show up on every page of my site? Are there tutorials for something similar to this?

Comment: There is also a widget functionality in wordpress, just paste your html into it. And it will appear on all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log into the dashboard, click on "Appearance" in the menu on the left, then choose "Widgets" and "Text". Choose the widget area you want it to appear in (these are theme-dependent, but can be customized any way you like), and then click "Add Widget".

Add a title, paste in your HTML, and click "Save". That's all there is to it.